How to assign a property to a variable from outside
How to assign a property milks to a variable activeMilk from outside.
The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressio.
I Googled the information and can’t find it.
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

please don't past code screenshots but the code itsel

You can access it through widget.milk, but it can't be called in the initializer scope.
So, override initState method and initialize it:
void initState(){

 activeMilk = widget.milk;
 super.initState();

 }

Hope it helps you.
btw, (in questions and answers) it's preferable to provide the code as text not an image .
